# Multiple expression controls in ONE FX controller

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

For the sake of a cleaner workspace is it possible to have multiple expression controls, such as slider controls, in the same FX control?

[image]

Basically, instead of seeing "Slider Control" and "Slider Control 2" I would like both of the actual sliders to reside under the same "Slider Control" heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not possible, as far as I know. (Tho perhaps it could be with a little programming, [using the ScriptUI API.](http://jongware.mit.edu/Sui/index_1.html) Here's the [complete reference](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/scripting/pdfs/javascript_tools_guide.pdf).)

However it is possible to rename the "Slider Control" and "Slider Control 2" labels to something more useful to you. That's what I usually do. Just click on the name and hit Return on the keyboard to rename.

Comment: I know to rename them, though do you know if the "Slider" portion can be renamed? It seems weird that every built-in slider property has a unique label, but I can't rename these. I suppose it doesn't matter if there can never be multiple in one FX control.

Comment: No, there's no easy way to rename the "Slider" portion. I looked more into the ScriptUI reference, though, and it does look as though you could create what you are talking about using a little bit of JavaScript programming. Depends on how much you'd care to tidy up I suppose!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Thought in the short term it isn't worth my effort, I will still check this out as I would love to learn how I can apply the ScriptUI stuff to help me later. :)